# Can I use #12 wire to connect switches for 30A motors?

Tags: electrical, cabling

I am wiring boat lift motors I'm starting at a 60 amp subpanel. I have a 30 amp e gfci breaker then about an 80 foot run to the lift motors. I have 10 gauge wire for that 80 foot run then into a switch box for the motors. can I drop down to 12 gauge wire for the switches and finish the runs to the motors in 12 gauge or do I have to maintain 10 gauge throughout the run to the motors.

Comment: What are the nameplate specs on your motors, and how many are you wiring up?

Comment: With the breaker being 30 amp #10 would be the minimum size wire.

Comment: In almost every case, a 30A breaker mandates 10AWG wire.  However, there's an exception in Code for certain motor applications in which a 30A breaker is allowed on a 20A circuit.  Hence ThreePhaseEel's interest in the motor ratings.  Are you doing this to be cheap or because you are getting hints about the exception?  Even if allowed, you could find yourself arguing with the inspector, who probably doesn't know the rule.

Comment: Remember that wire appears as a resistor to any circuit. The longer the wire the more resistance. So if you use the 10 gauge for most of it then drop it to 12 gauge, it is like adding even more resistance to that which the 10 gauge is already contributing. Just for drill, try out a voltage drop calculator program and get a feel for it yourself. I did a search and this is the first one that came up:
http://www.southwire.com/support/voltage-drop-calculator.htm

Comment: @Harper -- I suspect it's far easier to talk to an inspector about odd Code things when you can sit down with them and a Codebook, open it up, and outline what Code sections you were applying :)

Comment: I know on the 2 lifts I installed both were required to have 30 amp receptacles and the power to the boat houses required equipment GFCI's. Both were pontoon based (moved up and down with the tide) this may be different if a fixed structure but that may have been an Oregon or Bonneville requirement since they were on a river.

Comment: If a receptacle is involved, you must use 10AWG for 30A.  You can't count on it being a motor which fits the Article 430 exception.

Answer (score 1):

Factory lift switches are typically 10ga stranded. You got a lot of heat out there, just stick to 10. The 12 will work, but you'll end up killing your motor capacitors by the end of the first season or two.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can. The circuit breaker is protecting the wiring in case of partial (not zero ohm) short circuit. In the case you propose, assume a something metal falls across the motor terminals, allowing 30 amps continuously. The breaker will not trip and the 10AWG wire will be fine. However, the 12AWG wire will be overloaded and may melt or catch fire.

I think the only case where this would be allowed is if the 12AWG wiring were permanently attached to the motor by the manufacturer. This would correspond to a light fixture with built-in 18AWG wire on a 15 amp circuit. This is allowed but you cannot extend with more 18. All wiring you add to the circuit must be 14AWG or larger.

Comment: This is possibly a case where Art. 430 of the NEC applies -- we'd need motor nameplate specs to figure this out fully